# Setting italic in RichtText

Tags: xpages, stylesheet, richtext, italic

I am displaying richtext on my web page. and have added an italic text, but it does no show as italic, just normal text.

when I look in developer tool it looks like the xsp.css is setting font-style to inherit but I can't decide what it inherits from.

how can I find out what is causing the italic to not being set correctly?

[image]

I created an empty database with a form and an xpage and seem to get the same problem

[image]

[image]

the result is the same in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Answer (score 0):

In Developer Tools go to the second tab on the right called Computed. Here you can find "font-style" and see what style sheets are used to compute the styling.

Here's an example from an XPages app that uses the OneUI theme:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, try setting the theme to oneui in your empty test database (instead of the default "webstandard") just to see if that changes the styling

Comment: Isn't possible to use a custom theme and also NOT extend an existing theme?